# Rotate sliders WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, slider

I would like to rotate 4 sliders in WPF to create a custom control.

Here is my code :

```
<Grid Margin="20">
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Slider Name="Slider_Top_Left" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="75"     RenderTransformOrigin="0,0">
      <Slider.LayoutTransform>
         <RotateTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0" Angle="-135"/>
      </Slider.LayoutTransform>
   </Slider>
   <Slider Name="Slider_Top_Right" Grid.Column="1" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="75">
      <Slider.LayoutTransform>
         <RotateTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0" Angle="-45"/>
      </Slider.LayoutTransform>
   </Slider>
   <Slider Name="Slider_Bottom_Right" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="75">
      <Slider.LayoutTransform>
         <RotateTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0" Angle="45"/>
      </Slider.LayoutTransform>
   </Slider>
   <Slider Name="Slider_Bottom_Left" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="75">
      <Slider.LayoutTransform>
         <RotateTransform CenterX="-10" CenterY="-10" Angle="135"/>
      </Slider.LayoutTransform>
   </Slider>
</Grid>
```

The result :
[image: result]

What I want :[image: wanted]

I've tried without the grid definitions, with different centers (it didn't change anything).

I've followed the online help for layout transform but I can't make it work.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put Sliders in Grid properly and Rotate the `Grid`. If you decide later to add more elements to custom control, where will be no need to calculate any rotation angles/centers for them

```
<Grid Grid.Row="3">
    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="45"/>
    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!--top right-->
    <Slider Orientation="Vertical" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Slider.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
        </Slider.LayoutTransform>
    </Slider>
    <!--bottom left-->
    <Slider Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" 
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <!--top left-->
    <Slider Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <!--bottom right-->
    <Slider Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Slider.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
        </Slider.LayoutTransform>
    </Slider>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, really nice. However If I add a custom Template the top right slider and the bottom left are not working anymore ? (I've tried to create a local copy of the slider's template and put it in my slider's style)

Comment: @user2088807, bottom left slider is a standart slider with *vertical* orientation. rotation of grid shouldn't affect slider template at all. does your template work correctly with a vertical slider which is not in custom control?

Comment: Oh... You are right the default template is different if the slider has a vertical orientation. Problem solved :)

Answer (score 3):

This is how I did it:

```
<Grid>
    <Slider x:Name="slider" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="-50,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="75">
        <Slider.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0" Angle="-45"/>
        </Slider.LayoutTransform>
    </Slider>
    <Slider x:Name="slider1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="50,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="75">
        <Slider.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0" Angle="-135"/>
        </Slider.LayoutTransform>
    </Slider>
    <Slider x:Name="slider5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="50,-50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="75">
        <Slider.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0" Angle="135"/>
        </Slider.LayoutTransform>
    </Slider>
    <Slider x:Name="slider3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="-50,-50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="75">
        <Slider.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0" Angle="45"/>
        </Slider.LayoutTransform>
    </Slider>
</Grid>
```

[image: I can't embed images yet, please find my result in this link]

Answer (score 2):

I am not really sure what you want to achieve but still on based of image you have provided I am posting my code :

```
<Slider VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Slider.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>                    
                    <RotateTransform Angle="45"/>                    
                </TransformGroup>
            </Slider.RenderTransform>
</Slider>
```

Use angles of 45,-45,135,-135 to layout them as per your posted design.

A small tip : Next time you find any such issue, Go to properties of that control and look for all available properties.

Happy coding !!